# Change custom cursor style keyframe animation on hover

Tags: javascript, animation, keyframe

I have managed to create custom cursor from div with jQuery, can I also change the cursor style for example: (styling animation keyframes) when hovering over div.

Here is my html code that makes the custom cursor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .verline, .horline {
            border-radius: 20%;
            background-color: #121212;
            position :absolute;
            animation-duration: 400ms;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
        .horline {
            width: 50px;
            height: 3px;
            top: -3px;
            left: -25px;
            animation-name: hormove;
        }
        .verline {
            width: 3px;
            height: 50px;
            top: -27px;
            left: -2px;
            animation-name: vermove;
        }
        @keyframes hormove {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); top: -3px; left: -25px; }
            100% { transform: rotate(220deg); top: -19px; left: -25px; }
        }
        @keyframes vermove {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); top: -27px; left: -2px; }
            100% { transform: rotate(50deg); top: -12px; left: -2px; }
        }
        #hoverit {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cursor">
        <div class="horline"></div>
        <div class="verline"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hoverit"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var ElementCursor = {
        cursorElement: "",
        setCursor: function (cursorId) {
            $('html').css({
                'cursor': 'none'
            });
            $('html').mousedown(function (e) {return false;});
            ElementCursor.cursorElement = cursorId;
            ElementCursor.updateCursor();
        },
        removeCursor: function () {
            $('html').css({
                'cursor': ''
            });
            ElementCursor.cursorElement = '';
        },
        updateCursor: function () {
            $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                $('#' + ElementCursor.cursorElement).css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                        'top': e.pageY + 'px',
                        'left': e.pageX + 'px'
                });
            });
        }
    };
    ElementCursor.setCursor("cursor");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks a bit over complicated, could you explain better what you are trying to achieve?
There is a CSS pseudo-class called [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)
But it doesn't animate.

Comment: I need to make the cursor to be as + sign then when I hover to the right it should change the style to > and also when I move the mouse to left it should change the style to < . I already managed to make it > you can copy my code and test it it is working, but hovering still cant change

Comment: Have this plunker for now:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Iy7JX4?p=preview

Comment: Sure, Thank you, looking at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - just get offset and size of the div to hover on mouse move, use it to determine if the cursor div is left or right from its center and give it a corresponding class.

```
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        ElementCursor.cursorElement.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': e.pageY + 'px',
            'left': e.pageX + 'px'
        });
        var width = ElementCursor.hoverElement.outerWidth();
        var left = ElementCursor.hoverElement.offset().left;
        if (e.pageX > left + (width / 2)) {
          ElementCursor.cursorElement.addClass('right');
        } else {
          ElementCursor.cursorElement.removeClass('right');
        }
    });
    ElementCursor.hoverElement.mouseenter(function(e) {
      ElementCursor.cursorElement.addClass('in');
    });
    ElementCursor.hoverElement.mouseleave(function(e) {
      ElementCursor.cursorElement.removeClass('in');
    });
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/mIlI4BqXlpZ2IjiaNFFR?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, Can you have an example on how to achieve it, as change any css style of the cursor when hovering -- background color is ok I can change it, Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I need it animated cursor, + when it is at the middle of the page then it will animate to > when hovering to the left then < when hovering to the right, it is just changing the animation keyframes style when hovering thru javascript

Comment: I gave you a working answer including an example that actually does your job - wouldn't you mind voting for that?

Comment: Done, Thank you very much

Comment: I am sorry to ask again, I tried to solve it my self but failed to do, I need them to be opposite arrows, as when you go left the arrow should point to left side and same for the right, when I go to right the arrow should point to the right, Thank you